# What's the SDL-2.0 corresponding function for 'SDL_JoystickOpened'?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I tried to use `SDL_JoystickOpened()` in a SDL-2.0 code, but I got the error message *`SDL_JoystickOpened` was not declared in this scope*.

I've searched and found that `SDL_JoystickOpened()` no longer exists in SDL-2.0, but I didn't find the function that replaced it. Can anyone please tell me how can I replace `SDL_JoystickOpened()` in this piece of code:

```
SDL_Joystick *joy = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);
if (SDL_JoystickOpened(0) == 1)
{
    // do something
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @user13500 I've searched in the SDL 2.0 wiki (http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryJoystick) and the function wasn't there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickOpen) says the `SDL_JoystickOpen()` call returns a NULL pointer if it fails so just do a check for that:

```
SDL_Joystick *joy = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);
if (joy) {
    // joy is a valid pointer so do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative in 2.0 could be `SDL_JoystickGetAttached`

- [`SDL_JoystickOpened(int index)`](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdljoystickopened.html) (The old way SDL 1.2)

  > Determines whether a joystick has already been opened within the application. index refers to the N'th joystick on the system.
- [`SDL_JoystickGetAttached(SDL_Joystick* joystick)`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickGetAttached) (The new way SDL 2.0)

  > Returns SDL_TRUE if the joystick has been opened, SDL_FALSE if it has not; call [SDL_GetError()](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError) for more information

There is also an example in `test/testjoystick.c` of [SDL2 source-code](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) *(at least in SDL2-2.0.1)*.

---

Also note the [Joysticks](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#Joysticks) section of the *SDL 1.2 to 2.0 Migration Guide*. It gives various information on new features and ways in 2.0. It also links to the [GameController](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryGameController) section with e.g. [SDL_GameControllerGetJoystick](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GameControllerGetJoystick?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryGameController%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29).

Comment: @pbruno: Yes, if one do a check directly after `SDL_JoystickOpen()` it would be OK to check the pointer, but elsewhere it would most likely be more correct to use `SDL_JoystickGetAttached()` as, if I read it correctly, the `SDL_Joystick` won't become NULL on close or de-attachment. Would have tested it, but do not have any *joy* here :(